# How to maintain define functionality with custom #%module-begin?

Tags: racket

I want to do something with the strings produced by my custom language, for example to display them. I've created a module-begin something like this:

```
(define-syntax (module-begin stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ EXPR ...)
     #'(display (apply string-append (filter string? (list EXPR ...))))]))
```

However, this prevents me from using define in the language. I get the error "define: not allowed in an expression context".

How can I grab the strings without losing the ability to use define and other top-level expressions? Do I need to grab all the define's beforehand and move them to the beginning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The short answer

Use `make-wrapping-module-begin` to do the hard work for you.

```
(require syntax/wrap-modbeg)
(define-syntax module-begin (make-wrapping-module-begin #'wrap-expression))
(define-syntax (wrap-expression stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ expr) #'(println expr)]))
```

Change `wrap-expression` to do whatever you want with expressions. It isn't applied to definitions, `require` forms, etc. Note that you get the module-body expressions one at a time, not all at once.

## The long answer

You do not have the power to register module-level definitions, interpret `require` forms, etc. Only the macro expander and the primitive `#%plain-module-begin` form can do that. So your `module-begin` macro has to *cooperate* with them.

Your macro must use `local-expand` to partially expand each module-level form so that you can distinguish between the following:

- module-level definitions
- `require` and `provide` forms
- `begin` sequences, which need to be spliced into the module body
- expressions

When you get a definition or `require` or `provide` form, you just toss it to the *real* `#%plain-module-begin` primitive. The expressions you handle; again, however you like. And for `begin` forms, your recur on the sub-forms. The code looks something like this:

```
(define-syntax (module-begin stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ form ...)
     #'(#%plain-module-begin (wrap-module-form form) ...)]))

(define-syntax (wrap-module-form stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ form)
     (let ([e-form (local-expand #'form 'module #f)])
       (syntax-case e-form (begin define-syntaxes define-values #%require #%provide)
         [(define-syntaxes . _)
          e-form]
         [(define-values . _)
          e-form]
         [(#%require . _)
          e-form]
         [(#%provide . _)
          e-form]
         [(begin inner-form ...)
          #'(begin (wrap-module-form inner-form) ...)]
         [expr
          #'(wrap-expression expr)]))]))

(define-syntax (wrap-expression stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ expr) #'(println expr)]))
```

All the new code is basically what `make-wrapping-module-begin` is doing for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed and comprehensive answer. I have a follow up question, although this shows my ignorance I'm afraid. How do I wrap the expressions up into a list as per my question? As you say, the wrap-extension macro can only deal with the expressions one at a time.